# Issue with Jquery version?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Hi I have one weird problem. I am using Jquery version v1.8.2 in my project. So I want to upgrade the the version for the same reason I have updated to v1.11.0. After updating my Jquery files my on click events are not working. I didn't change the code. What is the reason of this ? Any suggestions please..

```
 <input id="btnDefaultSave" type="submit" data-theme="a" value="Save" data-mini="false">
```

javaScript:

```
$("#btnDefaultSave").click(function(){
alert("Test");
});
```

Comment: Please post your code here. Any console errors?

Comment: No I did not get any errors

Comment: I have added the code. please check it

Comment: Is the javascript running before the html? This is working when I try it: http://jsfiddle.net/7fAMy/

Comment: But on click event is not working. What is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$("#btnDefaultSave").click(function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("click","#btnDefaultSave",function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

If click event is still not working then your problem is not related to newer version of jQuery.